# kaggle kernel: Your kernel cannot use internet access for this competition

Tags: kaggle

I'm a recruit of kaggler.
I fork a open kernel and commit, when I submit my output, the button `Submit to Competition` not work, and info that "Your kernel cannot use internet access for this competition".

Answer (score 15):

To turn off internet access in a kaggle notebook or script.

1. Click settings in the right sidebar.
2. Next to "Internet" click 'on'
3. Commit

Answer (score 6):

Scroll bottom right and locate Notebook Options to turn off Internet in notebooks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just disable the internet setting button in the notebook, while committing the notebook.

Answer (score 1):

the problem come with the network setting, when commit the project, your kernel internet setting must blocked! and it will work!